# Regarding container creating during VMI create using kubevirt

Tags: docker, kubernetes, virtual-machine

### I am using kubernetes with docker. #kubectl, #Kubevirt

## When I create a VMI using containerDisk from docker.io registry I have found there is two container creating inside single pod (one is compute and another is volumecontainervolume)

cat centos.yaml | grep -ia3 centos-kubevirt-image

```
 volumes:

  - name: containervolume

  containerDisk:

    image: munnaeeebd/centos-kubevirt-image:latest

 - name: cloudinitvolume

  cloudInitNoCloud:

    userData: |-
```

kubectl get pod | grep centos

virt-launcher-centos-5kfvw   **2/2**     Running   0          21h

## But single container is create while using PVC and disk.img is uploaded via CDI

cat cirros-with-cirros-pvc.yaml | grep -ia3 cirros-pvc

```
  volumes:

   - name: containervolume

     persistentVolumeClaim:

     claimName: cirros-pvc

   - name: cloudinitvolume

     cloudInitNoCloud:

    userData: |-
```

kubectl get pod | grep cirros

virt-launcher-cirros-57x2r   **1/1**     Running   0          78m

my question is, is it normal that containerDisk create one additional container than PVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in [this GitHub post](https://github.com/kubevirt/kubevirt/issues/2877#issuecomment-552388789) it is designed behavior.

> The compute container contains the QEMU process with running Virtual
> Machine. The Virtual Machine reads the machine image from mounted
> volume served from the other volumecontainer.
>
> The second container
> only provides the data.
>
> With this design you have the benefit of packaging a Virtual Machine
> in the container image and uploading it to any container registry.
> Once it is uploaded, it can be used by KubeVirt as container disk.